# Enable responsive nav menu of bootstrap in tablet view(768px)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show responsive nav of bootstrap in tablet layout 768px. I tried but the button shows and the menus doesn't appear. At present in the tablet view menu shows normally but i don't like this style for tablet view at all.  Is there any way to show properly the responsive menu of bootstrap in tablet view ?

Project Link: http://zinan.me/kwok/

Comment: I think that the menu changes when browser width is less than 768, and usual tablet res is 768. you can change it in bootstrap.css -- find line with "@media (min-width: 768px)" and try to change it to @media (min-width: 769px)

Comment: cool, let me move it to an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the menu changes when browser width is less than 768, and usual tablet res is 768. you can change it in bootstrap.css - find line with

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
```

and try to change it to

```
@media (min-width: 769px)
```